# angular 2 Array comes as "undefined"

Tags: angular

Here is the situation.

I am trying to get a number from my database but every time I put the number into the Array(), it says undefined.

I am able to get the number as I can display it in my HTML but inside the array, does not work.

any idea why this is happening?

```js
import { Component,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RealEstatePhotography } from '../real-estate-photography';
import { RealEstatePhotographyService } from '../real-estate-photography.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-real-estate-photography-detail',
  templateUrl: './real-estate-photography-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./real-estate-photography-detail.component.css'],
  providers: [RealEstatePhotographyService],
})

export class RealEstatePhotographyDetailComponent implements OnInit {


realEstate;
amount
photos = Array(this.amount)

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _realEstatePhotographyService: RealEstatePhotographyService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}


  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let title = params['title'];
      let realEstate = this._realEstatePhotographyService.getItem(title).subscribe(realEstate => {
        this.realEstate = realEstate;
        this.amount = this.realEstate.amount

      });

    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amount is not defined at that time.  You need to update `photos` every time.

```
export class RealEstatePhotographyDetailComponent implements OnInit {


realEstate;
amount: Number;
photos: Photo[] = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _realEstatePhotographyService: RealEstatePhotographyService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}


  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let title = params['title'];
      let realEstate = this._realEstatePhotographyService.getItem(title).subscribe(realEstate => {
        this.realEstate = realEstate;
        this.amount = this.realEstate.amount;
        this.photos.push(realEstate.photo);
      });

    });
}
```

EDIT:

Just realized that you're probably trying to define the size of the array -- there's no need to do that in javascript.  Just declare it as an empty array and push in your photos as needed.

Comment: Dear Chrispy,

Thank you for your answer. It did not work like that but gave me an idea how to do it.
I could finally solve it. I just put 
photos = Array(this.realEstate.amount) 
inside the ngOnInit() method.

Again, thank you so much

Comment: No problem!  Note that "this.realEstate.amount" will always be undefined in your example at that point in time...